# QuicKblox ui not working after install Firebase Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, uinavigationbar, quickblox

I am facing one problem in chat Ui (objective C), it’s causing problem when i come back to chat screen by clicking on arrived notification , the navigation bar get hides .its working fine when i am inside at the app , the problem is coming only when i come back to app from notification tab , please let me know the issue. The problem only arise when i install `Firebase` framework inside application for Phone auth , it only arise in this case and when i remove that framework everything starts working fine again . i really need your support here that what thing is causing this to navigation bar.

Thanks

Comment: have you find any solution ?